# In-memory database for testing EJB with Hibernate and jUnit

Tags: hibernate, junit, ejb, dao, in-memory-database

I am trying to write unit tests for DAO classes using Hibernate and EJB 3. The database used for the application is PostgreSQL.

Is it a good idea to create Derby in memory database for testing these classes?
Could you provide me with some code how to set it up using jUnit 4.xx ?